# Possible to center this?

Tags: javascript, css

EDIT: I solved it with this: (Thanks for everyone who answered)

```
var intDuration = 50;
setInterval(
function(){
   $('#image').animate({"margin-left": "-=0.05%", "margin-top": "-=0.05%", "width": "+=0.1%"}, 'slow');
}, 
intDuration
);
```

So I have a JavaScript that adds 0.1% width every 50 ms, the only problem with this is that it becomes  uncentered after several seconds (because it is adding width). Is there any solution to this through javascript/css?
Here is the JavaScript:

```
    var intDuration = 50;
    setInterval(
       function(){
           $('#image').animate({"width": "+=0.1%"},'slow');
    }, 
       intDuration
    );
```

Here is my CSS: (Sorry if it's formatted terribly or a lot of things are redundant)

```
.image {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
background: #000;
}

.image img {
width: 1%;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="image">
 <image src="image.png" id='image'/>
```

JSFiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zane_/eERUA/

Comment: I'll suggest you to never use negative pixel positions like you've done in margin-top: -50 px;

Comment: :/ That seemed like the only way to make it "appear" centered.

Comment: is there a reason you are using setInterval with `.animate`, when you could just set the end width you want and a duration in `.animate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/4GrQk/2/

```
    .image img {
    width: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -0.5%;
    } 

    var intDuration = 50;
setInterval(

function () {
    var w = $('#image').width();
    var m = w/2;
    $('#image').animate({
        "width": "+=5%",
        "margin-left": -m+"%"
    }, 'slow');
},
intDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position:fixed`, so `text-align: center;` will center for you.

```
.image {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
background: #000;
}

.image img {
width: 1%;
}
```

Or use `display:block` and `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto`

```
.image {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #000;
    }

.image img {
width: 1%;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS and HTML file appears right, Try to alter your CSS file using this approach.

```
  .image
    {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #000;
    }
```

Below you need to set margin: auto;  It will automatically set your image in center position.

```
   .image img
   {
        width: 1%;
        position: fixed;
        margin: auto;
   }
```

Try this one, It may fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin: 0 auto;` or something similar to that on `#image`.

Also consider reproducing your problem in jsbin or jsfiddle and sharing it with us. That would help us to understand your problem more precisely and make it more likely for us to find a solution for it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zane_/eERUA/  
Here is the jsfiddle, as you can see it uses the top left pixel to act as the center.